# Typescript node-fetch import throws 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Tags: typescript, import, jestjs, ts-jest, node-fetch

As title says, I'm in trouble with the creation of a typescript library npm package. My issue come when trying to import node-fetch to perform fetch calls. I've created this [sample git](https://github.com/Daniele-Tentoni/ts-node-fetch-example) repo that reproduce my problem.

I've used those command to come at this point:

```sh
npm i --save-dev typescript ts-node jest @types/jest ts-jest
jest --init
npm i node-fetch
```

I've configured *package.json* as:

```json
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"files": [
  "/dist"
],
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest --coverage",
},
```

I've configured *tsconfig.json* as:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

My *jest.config.js* contains:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
};
```

When I run `npm text` the result is the following:

```
> tslib@0.1.0 test
> jest --coverage

 FAIL  tests/unit/index.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/d.tentoni/Documents/uni/tslib/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9
    import http from 'node:http';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import fetch from "node-fetch";
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | export async function scrape() {
      4 |   const response = await fetch(

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/scraper.ts:1:1)
```

Does anyone have any advice for me? How can I use node-fetch in my Typescript project?

Edit 1: using [Got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) installed with the command `npm i got` I obtain the same error.

Edit 2: added jest.config.js file content

Answer (score 0):

do you have a jest config? you have to specify to use ts-jest, as said in the 3rd line in jest, jest cant read non JS syntax (only Babel) but it doesnt look like you have a babel config file. this means Jest is trying to run TypeScript as JavaScript, which obviously throws a SyntaxError

try running
`npx ts-jest config:init`
or if you prefer yarn
`yarn ts-jest config:init`

Comment: Hello @pixel, in my example repo I have a jest.config.ts file with `preset: "ts-jest", testEnvironment: "node"` settings, the same that your command put inside the jest.config.js file he creates. When I run Jest with *.js config with `"test": "jest --coverage --config jest.config.js"`, the output doesn't change.